# What is the structure of a bound method and how does it work?

Tags: python, oop, methods

In general when we call upon a method on an object, python returns a bound method that wraps the actual method which has the `self` parameter. So we won't have to explicitly insert the self parameter.

So in a call like,

```
def f(a, b):
    print("Output is", b)

class C(object): 
   name = f 

x = C()
x.name(7)
```

**Output**

`Output is 7`

This happens because of the bound method returned by the call of `x.name`.

In this bound method, there are attributes `im_func` set to `f`, `im_class` set to `C`, and `im_self` set to `x`.

This is my understanding of bound method details.

I want to know the structure of this bound method object.

Is it generally something like,

```
def f(b):
    im_func=f
    im_class=C
    im_self=x
    im_func(im_self,b)
```

Correct me if I'm wrong I really appreciate it.

Comment: Do you know what descriptors are and how they work?

Comment: @timgeb yes I know it